Application Migration from Azure VM to AWS EC2 using AWS Application Migration Service
I am currently in the process of migrating my Azure VM to AWS EC2 using the AWS Application Migration Service (MGN). While the replication agent has been successfully installed and the source server is correctly identified, I am facing issues as the process gets stuck at step 2: Launch replication server ,failed .
I have used default subnets and security group is created by AWS Mirgration service . What is going wrong ?

Can you check the replication agent logs to find more details on the error : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mgn/latest/ug/Troubleshooting-Agent-Issues.html#MGN-Agent-Log

Hey , I contacted AWS support, and they informed me that I haven’t paid my AWS account bill, which caused certain services to be disabled. This resulted in the failure to launch the replication server.
